# Detect alphabetic or Numeric Key in a Datagridview control and send handled key to a textbox VB.BET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, event-handling, keyboard

I'm working on a Form that contains a datagridview and textbox, I need the datagridview detect any letter of the alphabet or numbers, then select the input and send the key pressed to input.

I can not find any solution for this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to attach an event handler to the cell editing control that is receiving the data that will respond to the KeyPress event. This can be done by handling the EditingControlShowing event.

Here is some basic code that does this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Dim c As Control
        c = e.Control

        AddHandler c.KeyPress, AddressOf Handle_KeyPress


    End Sub

    Protected Sub Handle_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            TextBox1.Text += e.KeyChar
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

There are other events that you can respond to such as KeyDown but KeyPress is generally preferred since it gives you a Char with the event args. With events like KeyDown you will have KeyCodes instead, which don't allow you to easily tell if the input was upper or lower case.

Comment: There you go - VB.Net is not exactly my first (or even second) language but this works in my example and the key idea with the adding an event to the underlying editing control is correct (the winforms controls are pretty much language independant so what works in C# works in VB.Net)