# Detect alphabet or numeric and then send them to textbox on a form?

Tags: vb.net

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163644/detect-alphabetic-or-numeric-key-in-a-datagridview-control-and-send-handled-key),

But in my case i have a form and textboxt, 
i need to detect alphabet or numeric and then send them to textbox same as above but on my form not datagrid.
How to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse (e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back)))
End Sub
```

Comment: thx for reply but i want to do that when textbox not in focus

Comment: Detect them from what source?

Comment: on **form**, can we do that? if you open the link, it use datagrid, but i dont want use that, i want to detect when form active or mouse over form but not in focus textbox.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Sorry, you right i do mistake i have button for set select automatically, i think it form where receive focus thx for all your reply, maybe i can help raise your reputation in other way, once again sorry and thx for your reply, this question is answered